# Should users see a notification about their flagged and deleted chat messages?

Tags: discussion, chat, notifications, chat-flags

Imagine a situation (which is currently happening) where some user's old inappropriate chat messages were deleted. That user is either out of chat, offline or otherwise not in chat to obviously notice the effects of that due to temporary suspension. When the suspension period ends (it's 30 minutes per message, so you can safely miss, say 16 deleted messages per 8 hour night) there is no indication (as far as I know) that anything happened or anything to learn from.

If a user is not a room owner, they can't see the deleted message and there may not be anyone else wishing to quote it, lest they be smitten also.

Do you think it would be useful to show the users their deleted message for educational/prevention purposes?

Comment: "If a user is not a room owner, they can't see the deleted message" - wrong, any user can see their own deleted chat messages. RO gets to see deleted messages of any other user as well.

Comment: I thought you can't see your own messages deleted by moderators? Or does that apply only for the posts on the main site?

Comment: Neither. You can always see your deleted questions, answers, or chat messages, no matter who deleted them (to see deleted chat message you have to view its history, either in the room scrolling up to older messages, or by manually changing URL if you have the message ID somehow). Only exception are comments. Also, you get a list of recently deleted questions or answers, no way to see your recently deleted chat messages, hence I upvoted this. :)

Comment: I mean there are cases when posts (maybe only questions?) are deleted "for reasons of moderation" and I think there was a time when you couldn't see those. Maybe I'm thinking of not my own posts deleted that way, even if I have the privilege to see posts deleted not by a moderator. I've been using the site for many years and I don't remember when it happened, but I'm pretty sure it did.

Comment: Maybe in the past we couldn't see our deleted answers when the question itself was deleted, but that was "fixed" at some point, and such users can see the deleted question and their own answer, but no other answers on the question, if there are any. (Talking about <10k rep users of course)

Answer (score 4):

Chat users can see their own deleted messages, but this isn't really about seeing the messages; it's about knowing to go look.  If you come back to the site hours after your messages and it's a busy room, you'll never notice that your messages aren't there.  Or, as you say, that you were suspended for them.

Letting users build up a record of suspensions *they don't even know about* seems like bad user experience, especially combined with the general practice of increasing suspension lengths with repeat offenses.  We should focus on fixing that.

We need a way to communicate to a chat user about these suspensions, but chat does not have mod messages the way the Q&A sites do.  We have (on Q&A) a couple cases where we provide "just in time" information about past poor contributions: if you try to flag something and your recent record is poor you get told "hey, go look at your recent flags; there are problems", and if you try to ask questions too quickly (or while question-blocked) you get messages about that ("slow down" and "no, not for a while", respectively).  Maybe we can do something similar for chat: when you come back to chat after a good night's sleep and click in the box to start composing a message (in any chat room), if you were suspended since the last time you talked, you get a message along the lines of "hey, you've had stuff flagged and deleted since you last talked; remember to be nice (link)" or similar.  I don't think we even need to provide the links; that gives the user enough of a hint that if he wants to go look he can, but if he already knows that yeah, that stuff he was saying was borderline, this is enough.

Information about suspensions is recorded with the chat user, as are the times the user was last seen and last posted, so this seems like a check that wouldn't be too hard to do.  We don't want to do the check on each and every message (some rooms are really busy), but since the case we're worried about is users not *noticing* they were chat-suspended, doing the check on the first message after the user enters a chat room should suffice.

Comment: In too many cases to ignore, I've seen the flagged and removed messages which may seem like something worthy of removing out of context. I'm not defending such messages, but in cases like that, the user would be completely oblivious to what they could have posted that resulted in removal and temporary suspension. I think this is when showing the exact message(s) is valuable. Just leaving it for guessing is inferior user experience in my mind.

Comment: @user1306322 I'm not averse to including a link to the most-recently flagged messages.  I haven't seen a lot of what you're talking about, but I don't spend lots of time handling chat flags.